# Android - How to Create Sqlite database with Tables

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to create a database with 3 tables and I am doing this like below:

```
public class DatabaseUtils extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
      private final Context myContext;  
      private SQLiteDatabase DataBase; 

      // Database creation sql statement
      private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CS = "create table "+ TABLE_CS + "(" + COLUMN_CS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_CE_CID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "+ COLUMN_CE_PID +" INTEGER NOT NULL);";
      private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SS = "create table "+ TABLE_SS + "(" + COLUMN_SS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_SUB_CID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "+ COLUMN_SUB_PID +" INTEGER NOT NULL);";
      private static final String CREATE_TABLE_AS = "create table "+ TABLE_AS + "(" + COLUMN_AS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_CID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "+ COLUMN_AID +" INTEGER NOT NULL);";

      public DatabaseUtils(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        DATABASE_PATH =  Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +"data/"+ context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_package);
        this.myContext = context;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CS);
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SS);
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_AS);
      }
      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DatabaseUtils.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "+ newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COMMENTS);
        onCreate(db);
      }
}
```

and in my Activity I am calling `DatabaseUtils` class in `onCreate` as below:

```
DatabaseUtils db = new DatabaseUtils(this);
```

but Database is not creating with the 3 tables. What am I doing wrong? BTW, I have all the string values correctly. Please help me how to create database.

Comment: where is your `DATABASE_VERSION`number defined? set it to a higher value, since it will only create new tables in `onCreate` if the value changes I think - and maybe you already executed the class before (with no tables).
Edit: ALSO you should define your `DATABASE_PATH ` BEFORE calling super - since you should pass this name (or / and path) of the database there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. `DatabaseUtils`' `onCreate()` is never called if i implement like below:

```
 DatabaseUtils db = new DatabaseUtils(this);
```

in `myActivity`'s `onCreate()` method. I need to call `getWritableDatabase()` in myActivity as below:

```
DatabaseUtils db = new DatabaseUtils(this);
db.getWritableDatabase();
```

Then `DatabaseUtils`' `onCreate()` will be called and tables are created.

Answer (score 0):

private void db_ini_create_table(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db){

```
    String str_sql = "create table [possible_know_persions]         ("+
                                                                        "[id]                       INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT               NOT NULL,"+
                                                                        "[adate]                    DATETIME        DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))   NOT NULL,"+
                                                                        "[current_userid]           INTEGER         DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL                              ,"+
                                                                        "[stranger_user_id]         INTEGER         DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL                              ,"+
                                                                        "[common_friend_count]      INTEGER         DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL                              ,"+
                                                                        "[common_game_count]        INTEGER         DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL                              ,"+
                                                                        "[user_account_type]        INTEGER         DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL                              ,"+
                                                                        "[verify_type]              INTEGER         NULL                                             "+
                                                                    ");";db.execSQL(str_sql); 
    str_sql = "CREATE INDEX [possible_stranger_user_id]     on [possible_know_persions] ("+"[stranger_user_id] asc "+");";db.execSQL(str_sql);      
}
```

this is a example for your reference